# IntelliJ IDEA - How to use merge conflict tool for all changes (including non-conflicting changes)? - Selectively merge all changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge

If you have used IntelliJ for git operations, you know that there is a special tool that appears when you are merging one branch into another, and conflicts arise. You're required to resolve these conflicts with this tool, as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html

My question is, is there a way to use this tool for ALL changes that you want to merge? For example, when I merge Branch A into Branch B, or when I pull changes from Remote Branch C into Local Branch D, I want that tool to appear so that I can selectively merge every single change/file exactly how I want, even if there aren't conflicts.

Comment: No, there is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @yole bummer... i guess maybe I'll try to request a feature?